# Conditional DataTemplate Selection using bindings Avalonia

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm new to Avalonia and I need to generate a List of Questions and answers for one of my projects. Up to now I have generated the Questions and and Answers as I needed. Code for the XAML

```
                <ItemsControl Items="{Binding Questions}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock
                                Classes="header"
                                Text="{Binding QuestionDescription}"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <ItemsControl Items="{Binding Answers}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox x:Name="{Binding AId}" Content="{Binding Answer}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

What I want now is to create different type of answering options (Radiobutton or checkbox) depending on the `AnswerType` value that I get from the `Questions` List. Here is my Question model

```
public class Question
{
    public string QId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
    public string AnswerType { get; set; }
}

public class Answers
{
    public string AId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data

```
  {
    "QId": "Q1",
    "QuectionDescription": "Quection01",
    "Answers": [
      {
        "AId": "Q1A1",
        "Answer": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "AId": "Q1A2",
        "Answer": "No"
      }
    ],
    "AnswerType": "RadioButton"
  },
  {
    "QId": "Q2",
    "QuectionDescription": "Quection02",
    "Answers": [
      {
        "AId": "Q2A1",
        "Answer": "Football"
      },
      {
        "AId": "Q2A2",
        "Answer": "Baseball"
      }
    ],
    "AnswerType": "CheckBox"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public class TemplateDictionaryConverter : Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate>, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string s)
            return this[s];
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

```xml
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding Answers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <Binding
            Path="AnswerType">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <example:TemplateDictionaryConverter>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBox">
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Answer}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioButton">
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding Answer}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </example:TemplateDictionaryConverter>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This was what I expecting. Tons of Thanks! @kekekeks